# How to add a startup option when starting a program through init

Tags: init

If you start a program at the command line like this "vuurmuur --no-check"

How do you add that same option when starting it through init?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "starting it through init"? As an Upstart job, SysV style Sxx-files in /etc/init, a `systemd` service, or a startup command for a particular user?

Comment: Starting it through an init script and how would I add this "--no-check" option when starting vuurmuur